# JQuery: How to find a tag having some value

Tags: jquery

In jquery, it is easy to find input elements having a value like:

```
$('input[value="some value"]');
```

but how do  you find a div with certain value:

```
<div>Hello There</div>
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
$('div[value="Hello There"]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('div:contains()')`.